# Angular multiple input field with remove options

Tags: angular

User will be able to add multiple emails, after entering the email, will add to a list and user will be able to remove from the list.
[image]

Comment: Do you need exact UI or just need logic with any UI

Comment: Just need logic to implement in Angular 14

Comment: did you tried angular material chips? [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9qhk5z) and [docs here](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In HTML page

```
<div class="parent-div">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>EMail</mat-label>
          <textarea matInput placeholder="Enter email" [(ngModel)]="email"
           (keyup.enter)="validateEmail()"> 
          </textarea>
      </mat-form-field>
     <div *ngFor="let email of emails" class="email-div">
         <mat-icon (click)="onDelete(email)">close</mat-icon>
         <span>{{email}}</span>
     <div>
</div>
```

### In TS file

Declare email variable and email array and implement validation function

```
//declaration
email: string = "";
emailArray: string[] = [];
//validation method
validateEmail() {
//do email validation here
//if it is valid email push email to emailArray
  if(validEmail) {
     this.emailArray.push(email);
     this.email ="";
  }else{
   //show error
   }
}
onDelete(email){
 var index = this.emailArray.findIndex((x)=> x=== email);
 if(index>-1){
    this.emailArray.splice(index, 1);
 }
}
```

Comment: if you use `<div *ngFor="let email of emails;let i=index">` you can pass the "index" to the function: `(click)="onDelete(i)"`, even you can use `(click)="emailArray.splice(i, 1)"`